# source bucket is not visible in Firebase Firestore import web tool even after giving required permission

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I'm following the official [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/export-import) on how to export and import firebase firestore data between 2 projects.
I'm able to export firestore data to a bucket. https://console.cloud.google.com/firestore/export

But I don't see that bucket when I try to import in a different firebase project. https://console.cloud.google.com/firestore/import

I gave `Storage Admin` permission to the destination service account i.e. `dest-proj@appspot.gserviceaccount.com` and both projects and this bucket is stored in the same multi-region (us-centeral)

I'm aware of the other way to import-export using gcloud shell but why this method is not working?

Answer (score 2):

The console only browse buckets that exist inside your current project. If data is coming from an outside bucket, you can simply type its entire file path in the Filename field as shown on the image below.

It will succeed if the service account running the import have the right IAM permission on the separate source bucket.
[image]